cloth physics clipping?
I have been working on physics for a skirt for a number of hours but I keep encountering the same issue seen in the video attached
https://imgur.com/a/Ra8p26F
I have object collision to 20 and self collision to 12, the distance settings between the collision and cloth object are the lowest they can be, and the mesh is paper thin so nothing should be overlapping. My only other thought is that this is an issue with the mesh itself and I would need to remesh the skirt to try and get a realistic result - what're your guys' thoughts? Any help would be appreciate because at this point I am just throwing myself at a wall lol.


Hello please share your file (remove the parts that are useless): https://blend-exchange.com/

Here is the link: 

It probably has to do with the topology, the faces are overlapping (see the image below), also don't forget to apply the scale. Maybe try this solution instead: use a larger and simpler object that will be your cage, make it invisible, give it a Cloth simulation, and give to your skirt a Mesh Deform modifier with this cage as Object.

